# Can I use etree.dump() to output to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to retrieve some data from some very large files and I figured out a way to get etree.dump() to select and output the exact thing I want to sys.stdout, but I can't figure out how to actually write it to a file.

The script has a GUI component and a lot of node selection options via the GUI, so I'll try to just show a snippet:

```
def print_output(briks, brik):
        for i in briks:
                etree.dump(brik)
```

This outputs my desired result to sys.stdout, but I want to redirect it to a text file or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
with open(save_file, 'a') as f:
    for i in brik.tier():
        f.write(i.tag, i.text)
```